# gcc/diab: keep unused function / sections

Tags: c++, gcc

I have a project in which I would like to keep certain functions / sections in the linking phase.

I tried:

```
static void stub_enforcer(void) __attribute__ ((used))
```

But this is for the compiler, and not for the linker.

Now that the linker takes charge and -gc-sections is used, the function I wanted to keep is "gone" :(

```
Removing unused section '.text.func2' in file './src/func2.o'
```

How can I instruct the linker not to remove the functions I need.

The reason I want to do this is a post build usage of the function, by changing stuff on the binary.

Comment: One possibility may be to "use" the function(s) in a conditional that _you_ know will never be true but that the compiler/linker can't: `if( argc == 1222333 ) { stub_enforcer(); }`

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution by controlling the LD script,

I have put the `stub_enforcer` in a section, and used `KEEP()` command to make sure the linker will not throw it.

It works.

Comment: If a symbol is to be reserved, one can use "-u" flag to keep specific symbols.