# How to keep unused function in firmware image use arm-none-eabi-gcc toolchain?

Tags: gcc, attributes, arm

I now try create a firmware image running STM32F0xx MCU. It's like flash algorithm,   provide some function call to control STM32F0xx MCU Pins, but it's more complicated than flash algorithm. So it will use STM32 HAL lib and Mbed lib.

The Compiler/linker use "-ffunction-sections" and "-fdata-sections" flags.

So I use "**attribute**((**used**))" to try keep function into firmware image, but it's failed.
arm-none-eabi-gcc toolchain version is 4.9.3.

My codes like this:

```
extern "C" {
__attribute__((__used__))  void writeSPI(uint32_t value)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < spiPinsNum; i++) {
        spiPins[i] = (((value >> i) & 0x01) != 0) ? 1 : 0;
    }
    __ASM volatile ("movs r0, #0"); // set R0 to 0 show success
    __ASM volatile ("bkpt  #0");   // halt MCU
}

}
```

After build succeed, the writeSPI symbol no in image. 
I also try `static` for function, the "-uXXXXX" flag, create a new section.

Question: How keep writeSPI function code with "-ffunction-sections" and "-fdata-sections" flags?

Comment: Please include full compilation commands. I suspect you still have `--gc-sections` or similar. Btw, what's a "flash algorithm"?

Comment: See: [`--gc-keep-exported`](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Options.html) which might be helpful.  The `__unused__` attribute is for the **compiler** and not the **LINKER**.  It means the compiler will generate code.  See also [what does KEEP mean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9827157/what-does-keep-mean-in-a-linker-script).

Comment: "flash algorithm" is a set functions Run in Target MCU. the code compile as position independent.

Comment: Because our need functions are complicated, when compile as position independent,  the binary code size will be very large. lots of unused functions(we don't need) included.  {I try use lib to reduce size, it's still large} . In short, we keep wanted unused functions and removed  unwanted functions into ELF image.

Comment: Sorry, forgot mention, the source code compile as position dependent.  use normal gcc link script file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [gcc/diab: keep unused function / sections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44363099/gcc-diab-keep-unused-function-sections)

Answer (score 0):

One way to ensure a wanted function doesn't get garbage collected is to create a function pointer to it within a method that *is* used. You don't have to do anything with the function pointer, just initialize it.

```
void(*dummy)(uint32_t)=&writeSPI;
```

An alternative would be to omit the `-ffunction-sections` flag from the compilation units that contain functions that should not be stripped, but that may involve significant restructuring of your code base.

Comment: Thanks! Cheat gcc compiler will be working.  But is there any compiler/linker flag, #pragma,  __attribute__ ... force special unused function link into ELF image?

Comment: I thought that `__attribute__ ((section (".text")))` or something like that would work but it didn't work for me. The idea is that you force the function into a section that cannot be garbage collected.